# Combining every pair of values into tuples in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, tuples

I have a json that looks like this:

```
{
    "cols": [
        "id",
        "value"
    ],
    "data": [
        [
            1,
            "0.10259593440335"
        ],
        [
            2,
            "0.0061205302736639"
        ],
        [
            3,
            "-0.36367513456978"
        ],
        [
            4,
            "0.080167833573921"
        ],
        .
        .
        .
```

And here is my code that uses PySpark to read the data:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '.')
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

def strip(line: str):
    if line[-1] == ',':
        return float(line[3:-1])
    else:
        return float(line[4:-1])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName("airports").setMaster("local[*]")

    sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

    json = sc.textFile("dataMay-31-2017.json")
    jsonCol = json.filter(lambda line: '\t\t\t' in line)
    jsonCol = jsonCol.map(strip)
```

After that last map operation I have and RDD which contains elements as follows:

```
[1.0, 0.10259593440335, 2.0, 0.0061205302736639, 3.0, -0.36367513456978, 4.0, 0.080167833573921,...
```

Now I would like to perform an operation that would give me and RDD of tuples of two:

```
[(1.0, 0.10259593440335), (2.0, 0.0061205302736639), (3.0, -0.36367513456978), (4.0, 0.080167833573921),...
```

What would be the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
df=spark.read.json('dataMay-31-2017.json',multiLine=True)
ndf=df.select(explode(df.data))
ndf.rdd.map(lambda r:tuple(r.col))
```

Comment: Thank you, one more question though, I would like to get the tuple with the smallest value. When I call myRDD.min() it gives me the minimum by the key. Is there a way to use myRDD.min() but in a way that I get the tuple with the minimal value, not key?

Comment: ndf.rdd.map(lambda r:tuple(r.col)).sortBy(lambda x:x[1]).take(1)